# Riverpod state is null after returning in the build of the notifier

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I have this notifier:

```
class AsyncPlayerNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<PlayerData> {
  @override
  Future<PlayerData> build() async {
    return const PlayerData(
        PlayerRequestState: AsyncAction.initial(), player: null);
  }

  Future<void> setPlayer(Player player) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    // verify player
    // ...
    state = AsyncValue<PlayernData>.data(state.value!.copyWith(
        player: player,
        PlayerRequestState: const AsyncAction.success(null)));
  }
}

final playerNotifierProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<AsyncPlayerNotifier, PlayerData>(
        () {
  return AsyncPlayerNotifier();
});
```

After I call `ref.read(playerNotifierProvider.notifier).setPlayer(myPlayer)` I see that the `build` function is called, and right after that the `setPlayer` function is called. The problem is that the `state.value` inside the `setPlayer` function is null. If in the `build` function I do `state = ...`, then the state is not null, but the Riverpod docs show that you need to return the state in the `build` function, and not set it.

Comment: The `state.value` inside `setPlayer` is null, isn't it because you set the state to `AsyncValue.loading()`?

Comment: But if in build I call "state = const AsyncValue.data(PlayerData(
        playerRequestState: AsyncAction.initial(), connector: null))" then the state.value is not null after calling "state = const AsyncValue.loading();" in setPlayer. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you call ref.read(....) you should be in init/destroy method. if your are in build you should call ref.watch(...) . In that case flutter recall build(...) because in setPlayer(...) you have changed the state, thus the method force to rebuild every widget that depends on the notifier. The state is null because your notifier is async, and you nulled the state with AsyncValue.loading(). You shoud use the when(...) method on ref or the new pattern matching.
Take a look at their example:

```
class TodoListView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TodoListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // rebuild the widget when the todo list changes
    final asyncTodos = ref.watch(asyncTodosProvider);

    // Let's render the todos in a scrollable list view
    return switch (asyncTodos) {
          AsyncData(:final value) => ListView(
              children: [
                for (final todo in value)
                  CheckboxListTile(    
                    value: todo.completed,
            // When tapping on the todo, change its completed status
                onChanged: (value) {
                  ref.read(asyncTodosProvider.notifier).toggle(todo.id);
                },
                title: Text(todo.description),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),
  _ => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
};
  }
}
```

Using the switch(...) on ASyncData/AsyncError you are sure not to take a null state   error

Comment: "and you nulled the state with AsyncValue.loading()" - But if in build I call "state = const AsyncValue.data(PlayerData(
        playerRequestState: AsyncAction.initial(), connector: null))" then the state.value is not null after calling "state = const AsyncValue.loading();" in setPlayer. why is that?

Comment: in the setPlayer() you make : state = ASyncValue...; then you wrote: state.value!  In this case value is null. I think that the problem is that the state is async and you cannot make state.value! . I suggest you be sure that value is not null: state.value == null ? await _fetchData(...) : stata.requiredValue; you must write this line at the begin of setPlayer(...). If you don't' want to re-fecth data, you can pass it by Widget

Comment: But why state.value is null? If I change build() to include 'state = <some state>' and then return <some state> then state.value is not null (inside setPlayer) and if build() only has 'return <some state>' then state.value is null inside setPlayer.